# RewriteRule apache unable to open some file names

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with rewriterules in appache.

when I have this code :

> RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]

it cannot open the page , but if I change the rule to :

> RewriteRule ^profile2/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]

It opens it with no problem at all.

This problem happens to all of my rules

Edit: profile is an example and I checked that no folder with that name exists on my host. 
Another  thing is that no matter what, I cannot choose same name like my files . forexample if I want to redirect cup/  cup.php   i have the the above problem.

Comment: are there other rules in your htaccess file and may conflict with this one?

Comment: nah, I just removed other rules, but not solved

Comment: @SatishGadhave what about httpd rules , like filenames are restricted in rewrite rules ?!

Comment: profile.php is very common file name and i dont think it could have restricted. are you sure URL you testing with is in lower case?

Comment: yep , It's not about only profile.php  I checked any file name you think of !!! I cannot use same name as my file name with rewriterule

Comment: Add a `RewriteCond` that checks whether the requested filename does not correspond to an existing file first.

Answer (score 0):

if file exists with the same name as parameter rewriterules fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Options -MultiViews**

Before your rule, please add the above line to your htaccess file.

See the use of MultiViews on the following link
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews